# Argument group is of type 'dict' and we were unable to convert to list

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to break some commonly-done AWS tasks into roles so that I can use them more nimbly in playbooks and have hit an unexpected roadblock. I can't figure this one out:

This play works just fine directly with 'group' defined as a list directly in the task:

```
ec2:
 image: "{{image}}"
 region: "{{region}}"
 group: [ "ssh", "outbound" ]
 [... other stuff]
```

But Ansible fails if I instead put the play in a role and define 'groups' in its 'defaults/main.yml' file like this:

```
groups: ["ssh", "outbound"]
```

The play now looks like this:

```
ec2:
 image: "{{image}}"
 region: "{{region}}"
 group: "{{groups}}"
 [... other stuff]
```

Ansible fails with this message, seeming to think my variable is a dict, not a list:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "argument group is of type <type 'dict'> and we were unable to convert to list"}
```

I'm either missing something obvious or have run into a limitation of Ansible's variable parsing. Anyone have any insight into this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`groups` is a reserved variable, a [magic variable](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts) holding all groups of your inventory in a dict, each group item holding all hosts of that group.

Your approach should be working by picking any other variable name.

Comment: Thanks! I actually ran into a similar problem trying to use 'port' as a variable...